# UnsatisfiedDependencyException in github action, but working correctly in local

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have the following github action. I have the branch that is working perfectly and pass all tests in my IntelliJ IDE. But in gihub action, only 3 out of 9 test suites run successfully, for the rests, it throws `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` exception. I have checked for the @service annotations and file locations. All are in order. Can anyone help me find out what is going on.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'feature/*'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: 'Set up archived Oracle JDK 17.0.2'
        uses: oracle-actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          website: oracle.com
          release: 17
          version: 17.0.2
      - name: 'check java version'
        run: java -version

      - name: Install Maven
        uses: yuzhiyongcn/setup-maven@v1.0.0
        with:
          maven-version: 3.9.3 # optional, default is 3.8.2

      - name: Setup Dependency
        run: mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V

      - name: Build and Test
        run: mvn verify
```